# Virtual Biometric fingerprint device output to give i/p other s/w

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, fingerprint, biometrics

We're using a software in which, a Biometric fingerprint scanner (Customer Login functionality) for customers (Govt. Shop) and after scanning fingerprint in that device, the customer receives a on their mobile phone to login.

What we want to do :

We want to help customers : to provide this facility without coming physically at the shop. The customer have to come shop only once to record their fingerprint ( The finger print will be scanned through any other application, may be any application software from net or I've knowledge of desktop applications in `vb.net` so i can develop it.

Scenario : When there is any need of shopping, the customer will contact us via mobile phone and we'll use their fingerprint ( which is already scanned via the application mentioned above) to login into that shopping software.

so when login needed the application will give **virtual biometric fingerprint** output to the shopping software and thus login can be done. further, the shopping software will send message to customer; customer will give the code via call and we'll be able to login into their account and will shop for them.

Note: Is there any such kind of application available that can scan finger print and give fingerprint output (**virtual finger print**) for other software when needed ..

Device we're Using :

```
"secugen" biometric fingerprint scanner
```

Comment: This is too broad and opinion-based question.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin hmmm but not exactly opinion ... this is the actual problem